# Angular2 adding JSON data to single page app

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-services

I have very recently started trying to work with Angular 2 and am stuck on trying to add JSON data to a service. I've run through the official tutorial and the documentation about HTTP requests, but can't seem to get this to work. The base code for the service is as follows -

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Address } from './models/address';


const AddressEndpoint = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

@Injectable()
export class AddressService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Observable<Address[]> {
    throw new Error('NOT IMPLEMENTED');
  }

  get(id: number): Address {
    throw new Error('NOT IMPLEMENTED');
  }

  insert(addr: Address) {
    throw new Error('NOT IMPLEMENTED');
  }

  remove(id: number) {
    throw new Error('NOT IMPLEMENTED');
  }
```

How do I access the AddressEndpoint const within each of the class methods and how do I specific which piece of data I want to GET for each request? I I then need to feed this to an Address model with the following code and am again a bit unclear as to how I'd push my pulled data here.

```js
export class Address {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  address: {
    street?: string,
    suite?: string,
    city?: string,
    zipcode?: string
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's somewhat hard to answer as there is little information regarding the structure of the JSON, how the data is structured, and what data you expect to retrieve with each method stubbed in `AddressService`.

An option for accessing a common property would be to simply use a class property, such as a `readonly` one, on AddressService, that you can access the value using `this` within any of the `AddressService` class methods:

```
@Injectable()
export class AddressService {
    readonly AddressEndpoint = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    get(id: number): Observable<Address> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.AddressEndpoint}/${id}`);
    }
}
```

In terms of mapping the result to a type/model, such as `Address` in your case, you can [typecheck the response](https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response) with `HttpClient` as follows:

```
get(id: number): Observable<Address> {
    return this.http.get<Address>(`${this.AddressEndpoint}/${id}`);
}
```

Otherwise, you can utilize the rjxs `map` operator to transform the response to the `Address` type/model as need before some class `subscribe()` to it:

```
get(id: number): Observable<Address> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.AddressEndpoint}/${id}`).map(data => new Address(data['someProperty'], data['someOtherProperty']);
}
```

**Note:** If you using @angular/cli and will be using `HttpClient` to execute something like a `get()` to a JSON file located alongside this `AddressService`, you will want to add the file to the `assets` array property of `angular-cli.json`.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to save your endpoint address in separate file (among other constants) something like this:

```
export const endPointAddress = "http://youraddress".
```

Then you may import this const and use as always.
In real world app you will create class that will have two fields - one for endpoint for dev environment, another one - for production or stage.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are asking how to send JSON to your REST Endpoint and how to retrieve the data from the Response into your model object. If this is the case, continue reading :)

Here is an example implementation of a GET request:

```
/**
* Generic method that sends an HTTP GET request at the configured serviceUrl
* @returns {Observable<T>} - contains the converted data extracted from the response
*/
public get<T>(url: string): Observable<T[]> {

return this.httpClient.get<MyResponse<T[]>>(url, {observe: 'response'})
  .do(res => this.logResponse(res))
  .filter(res => res.status === 200)
  .map(res => res.body.data)
  .catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => this.handleError(error));
}
```

When calling the method like this `this.httpClient.get<MyResponse<T[]>>`, we can tell the httpClient that we expect the response to be of type `MyReponse<T[]>`. 
`MyResponse` is the model describing how the reponse looks like, much like a wrapper:

```
/**
* Template class for the backend JSON response which looks like this:
* {
*    "data": <DATA_FROM_BACKEND>
* }
*/
export class MyResponse<T> {

  constructor(public data: T) {
  }

}
```

`<T[]>` is the type of the data object wrapped by MyResponse. In your case it would be smth like this `this.httpClient.get<MyResponse<Address[]>>` and it will describe a JSON response that looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
     {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John Doe",
      "address": {
          "city": "NY",
          "street": "Wall Street",
          "suite": "string",
          "zipcode": "007"
      },
      {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "John Doe2",
      "address": {
          "city": "NY",
          "street": "Wall Street",
          "suite": "string",
          "zipcode": "007"
      }
    ]
}
```

`{observe: 'response'}` tells `HttpClient` that you want to observe the response in order to operate on the entire response object and do things like these:

```
.filter(res => res.status === 200)
.map(res => res.body.data)
```

`.map(res => res.body.data)` here we transform the `data` attribute (MyResponse.data) from JSON to type `<T>`.

To adapt it to your use case, you would have smth like this in your service:

```
public get(url: string): Observable<Address[]> {

return this.httpClient.get<MyResponse<Address[]>>(url, {observe: 'response'})
  .do(res => this.logResponse(res))
  .filter(res => res.status === 200)
  .map(res => res.body.data)
  .catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => this.handleError(error));
}
```

and you would use this in your component like this:

```
this.formService.get('/users').subscribe(address => {
    console.log(address);
  });
```

Your URL has to be something like this `/users`. You don't need to specify the full path.

And here is an example of a POST:

```
public insert(url: string, entity: Address): Observable<number> {
let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

return this.httpClient.post<ImResponse<number>>(url, JSON.stringify(entity), {
  headers: headers,
  observe: 'response'
})
  .do(res => this.logResponse(res))
  .filter(response => response.status === 201)
  .map(response => response.body.data)
  .catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => this.handleError(error));
}
```

and use it like this:

```
  let entity: Address = new Address();
 this.formService.insert('/users', entity).subscribe(id => {
    console.log(id);
  });
```

**NOTE**: The code above is an adaptation from actual production code. I have not tested it and may contain typos.

I hope these examples would help you implement the other methods as well.